# Add key to multiple list of JSON

Tags: json, laravel

Using `Laravel5.1` ...

I'm trying to convert this JSON:

```
"[{"John Doe":"john.gmail.com"},{"Frank Smith":"frank@frank.com"},{"Jie Brent":"jie@gmail.com"},{"Jeffrey Manney":"jeff17@gmail.com"}]"
```

To this:

```
"[{"name":"John Doe", "email":"john.gmail.com"},{"name":"Frank Smith", "email":"frank@frank.com"},{"name":"Jie Brent", "email":"jie@gmail.com"},{"name":"Jeffrey Manney", "email":"jeff17@gmail.com"}]"
```

This is my code:

```
$users_storage = [];

foreach($rcf_and_rcfm_users as $key => $user){
   $users_storage[][$key] = $user;
}

$users = json_encode($users_storage);

dd($users);
```

The `$rcf_and_rcfm_users` variable is a collection of users from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly.

```
$users_storage = [];

foreach($rcf_and_rcfm_users as $name => $email){
   $users_storage[] = [
      'name' => $name,
      'email' => $email,
   ];
}

$users = json_encode($users_storage);

dd($users);
```

I think this is what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Holy cow! Didn't think about arrays.